# Add object to ManyToMany field using CreateModelMixin.create()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use `mixins.CreateModelMixin.create` to create object, but also I need to add `request.user` to `m2m` fields in it. So my idea is to catch the object from `self.create()` and than filally `make obj.users.add(user)`. But CreateModelMixin return only `responce`. How can I get an object from `.create`? Is it a better way to add user? Can I user `super` (not good in it)? Thanks!

**ADDED:**

I can use `perform_create()` and catch object here, but it makes code bigger and repeat `.create()` mostly, so I don't think that is a right way.

**ADDED:**

Code I user now:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['POST'], serializer_class=CompanyAdminSerializer)
def create_company(self, request):
    user = self.request.user
    if user.user_of_company.exists():
        raise NotAcceptable(detail='Only one company allowed')
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    company = serializer.save()
    company.users.add(user)
    company.admin_users.add(user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: you should post the code you are using now.

Comment: @Ykh check the code I added and use now. It copies .save exept that .add method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch the instance from `create` you will have to override the `create` method. 
The simplest way would be to override the `perform_create` method.

`.save()` returns the instance of the created object. [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L733)

Your code will look like the following:

```
#Assuming you're using CreateAPIView
class New_Create(CreateAPIView):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        obj = serializer.save()
        #Adding to M2M
        obj.users.add(self.request.user)
```

DRF Serializers do not support [M2M create/update](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L922) out of the box.

EDIT: 
I do not recommend overriding the `create` method. The `perform_create` method has been created to serve exactly this purpose. You can access the instance only after `.save()` has been called. So, after calling `.save()` on the serializer you can update the instance however you want. Two ways to access the instance are: 
1) Use the object being returned by the `.save` method (as shown above)
2) You can use serializer.instance. (Again you can only access the `instance` after `.save` has been called. )

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you've described the way I do it now. I hope to find a simplier way. Just check the code I added and CreateModelMixin code - it's the same exept that add to m2m. I'm trying to catch object from there, or pass inside .create .add method, maybe via super.

Comment: @D.Make. Updated my answer.